# DataFrame Filter Row keeps Saying "string" to "int" even though no "int"

Tags: c#, dataframe, filter, row

I am currently creating a filter for a DataFrame that is supposed to filter out string based upon a list of strings I don't want in the column.

The Column when I look at the DataFrame says that it is in-fact System.String data type.

However, what puzzles me the most is that I recieve the error, even though it doesn't know what the column would be since it doesn't directly reference the DataFrame. The error I receive is the following :

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'RoslynCS1503
class System.String
Represents text as a sequence of UTF-16 code units.
```

It says this error highlighting the "stringcolumn" section when I declare `row["stringcolumn"]`.

```
// Load the data into the data frame
var dataFrame = DataFrame.LoadCsv(dataPath);

// To get a preview of the column datatypes, run Info().
Console.WriteLine(dataFrame.Info());

// To get a summary of the data, run Description().

Console.WriteLine(dataFrame.Description());

// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Removing the unwanted String Rows
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

// Creating a list of bad strings to remove from the original data frame

List<string> stringsToRemove = new List<string> {"string123", "stringabc"};

// Define the filter condition: Define a delegate that takes a DataFrameRow and returns true
// if the row should be included in the output DataFrame and false otherwise. This delegate is 
// invoked for each row in the DataFrame.

// Func<DataFrameRow, bool> filterCondition = row => !stringsToRemove.Contains(row.GetAs<string>("stringcolumn"));

// Func<DataFrameRow, bool> filterCondition = row => !stringsToRemove.Contains((string)row["stringcolumn"]);

Func<DataFrameRow, bool> filterCondition = row =>
{
    string badString = row["stringcolumn"].ToString(); // Access the serialnumber value from the row
    return !stringsToRemove.Contains(badString);
};
```

You can see I have tried other methods, and they return the same result. I'm currently using VS Code as my IDE.

I was expecting it to remove the serial numbers, however all references state that this is the proper way to format this, and I don't understand why VS code says it's bad, since how could it possibly check for a string if it doesn't even have reference to the DataFrame column in that filter?

Comment: What type is `row`? Does it implement a `item[string]` indexed property (like a `Dictionary<string, TValue>`) or just an `item[int]` one, like an array

Comment: I ended up adding the int value itself for the column, since the examples I used kept saying to replace with the name of the column, and when I used the position of the column it appeared to work. Gives me a warning for Null values, which I put a remove null function before it to get it working.

Now for `DataFrame filteredDataFrame = dataFrame.Filter(filterCondition);` I get an error;

`Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Func<Microsoft.Data.Analysis.DataFrameRow, bool>' to 'Microsoft.Data.Analysis.PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<bool>'RoslynCS1503`

Comment: Wild guess. I think you may be hitting the frustrating issue that's similar to why `delegate bool Predicate<in T>(T obj)` is a different type than `delegate TResult Func<in T, out TResult>(T arg);` (where `TResult` is bool).  Two delegates, declared differently (even though they have the same underlying meaning and can represent the same functions or lambdas) have two different underlying types and there is no way to convert from one to the other.  Consider changing the type of your declaration of `row` to `Microsoft.Data.Analysis.PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<bool> filterCondition = row => etc`

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion, it does seem to resolve the type issue, however, now I have an issue with the lambda expression, and converting it to the type I need. 

`Microsoft.Data.Analysis.PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<bool> filterCondition = row => etc.`

Now gives me an error over `=>` and says:

`Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<bool>'because it is not a delegate type RoslynCS1660`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ElementwiseNotEquals()`:

```cs
var filteredDataFrame = dataFrame.Filter(
    dataFrame["stringcolumn"].ElementwiseNotEquals(stringsToRemove));
```

There are several methods that can be applied this way. They are all listed here undder methods: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.analysis.dataframe.elementwisenotequals?view=ml-dotnet-preview